# Repair weird characters in Database

Tags: sql, database, utf

I had a problem with UTF-8. So now many records are broken and have weird characters in them like..

**donc de faÃ§on crÃ©ative**

Any way i can repair all of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the Following stored procedure i'd developed to remove any character and replace with required one.

```
CREATE PROC CHAR_REPLACER
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @CHARTOREPLACE VARCHAR(MAX)='"Ã§©'   --SIMPLY PUT HERE A CHAR You want to Replace
DECLARE @REPLACEWITH VARCHAR(MAX)=' ASC'     --SIMPLY PUT HERE A REPLACING CHAR

DECLARE @POS INT=1

SELECT * FROM A  --DATA BEFORE

WHILE @POS<LEN(@CHARTOREPLACE)
BEGIN
   UPDATE A SET f1=REPLACE(F1,SUBSTRING(@CHARTOREPLACE,@POS,1),SUBSTRING(@REPLACEWITH,@POS,1))
   WHERE CHARINDEX(SUBSTRING(@CHARTOREPLACE,@POS,1),F1,1)>0
   SET @POS=@POS+1
END

SELECT * FROM A  --DATA AFTER
END
```

Please Modify Those Variables as a Parameters so you dont have to Alter Each time when you want to Add the New Character in that Array..